# MySql multiple where conditions - only match first correct condition

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, ifnull

With data similar to the table below:

```
|  id  |    e_date    |  e_time |  place | person| ref  |ref_type| 
|  10  |  2015-08-03  |  10:30  |  work  |  tony | 1234 |   A    |
|  25  |  2015-08-03  |  10:30  |  work  |  NULL | NULL |   A    |
|  37  |  2015-08-03  |  NULL   |  work  |  tony | NULL |   A    |
|  99  |  2015-08-03  |  10:30  |  work  |  fred | 1234 |   B    |
```

What's the best method to get ***only*** the 1st match of a series of  conditions (of desc importance) in a MySQL `WHERE` clause ?

- match the `ref` field
- if no matches in `ref` field, then match on `e_date+e_time+place` fields
- if no matches on `ref` or `e_date+e_time+place` then match on `e_date+place+person`

The aim here is to get the best single row match - based on a descending series of criteria - and only use the criteria if the preceding criteria isn't fulfilled.

My first attempt at query looked like:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE ref_type = 'A' AND (
  ref = '1234'
  OR
  (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work')
  OR
  (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony')
)
```

but since `OR` is inclusive (not sequential), this returns rows `10`, `25` and `37` - see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbce0/2)

I could `ORDER BY ref DESC` and `LIMIT 1` (if I modify to `SELECT id, ref FROM...`) but that doesn't help me if I have no `ref` value and have to differentiate by either of the 2nd or 3rd conditions

My next attempt uses nested `IF` conditions in the `WHERE` clause like :

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE ref_type = 'A' AND (
  IF(ref = 1234, 
    ref = 1234,
    IF(e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work', 
       e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work',
       e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony'
    )
  )
)
```

However, this returns also rows `10`, `25` and `37` - see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbce0/1)

Also tried using `IFNULL` :

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE ref_type = 'A' AND 
  IFNULL(ref = '1234', 
    IFNULL(e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work',
      e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony')
  )
```

Which returns rows `10` and `25`  - see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbce0/4)

What's the best way to write this query ?

I'm using php - and I could run 3 separate sequential queries and use php conditionals on each result - but I'd like to use a single db query given the millions of times this code will be run per hour.

Comment: What do you mean by "`ORDER BY ref DESC LIMIT 1` doesn't help me if I have no `ref` value "? You are fetching an `id` column not `ref`.So using `LIMIT 1` on the first query(with simple `OR`) clause should work right?

Comment: you tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`, which one are you using ?

Comment: @Pholochtairze `mysql` - sorry will remove the `sql-server` tag

Comment: @Kamehameha - yes correct - i'd need to `SELECT id, ref FROM...` in that case - i'll update for clarity - but as noted in the question, a `LIMIT` doesn't help me distinguish from conditions 2 and 3 if the 1st `ref` condition is not fulfilled

Answer (score 3):

The only way (that I know of) is to run the query multiple times with a different `where`. You can do that as a single query with union:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <most important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <less important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <even less important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    ...
) as t
LIMIT 1
```

Or you can just run them one by one and stop if there is a result.

Comment: Is this also possible?`SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <most important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <less important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <even less important condition> LIMIT 1
    UNION
    ...
) as t
LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT <stuff> FROM <table>` i mean a union inside a union?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    id
FROM my_table
WHERE ref_type = 'A'
ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN ref = '1234' 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 
        (CASE WHEN e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work' 
            THEN 2
            ELSE
                (CASE WHEN (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony')
                    THEN 3
                    ELSE 4
                END)
        END)
END)
LIMIT 1
```

Or, if it had a long running time create a view with the following query :

```
SELECT
    id,
    (CASE WHEN ref = '1234' 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 
            (CASE WHEN e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work' 
                THEN 2
                ELSE
                    (CASE WHEN (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony')
                        THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
                    END)
            END)
    END) AS "case_field"
FROM my_table
WHERE ref_type = 'A'
```

And then just run :

```
SELECT id FROM your_view ORDER BY case_field LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The first query seems to be working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your logic, you want to return the row with `ref` if it's not null. If it's null, then the one with `e_time` not null. And finally, the one with `person` not null. So, maybe you could use this ordering to your first attempt query?

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE ref_type = 'A' AND (
  ref = '1234'
  OR
  (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work')
  OR
  (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony')
)
ORDER BY ref DESC,
  e_time DESC,
  person DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbce0/6 - gives results in order `10` `37` `25` - for this data set the required `ORDER BY` clause would need `ASC` on `e_time` to get the conditions sequence correct - so unfortunately it's a 'fragile' solution because while I can force it to work on the current data in this case, required sort it that could be different for another data set

Comment: * the required order `ASC` or `DESC` could be different for another data set, even when using the same `WHERE` conditions

Answer (score 0):

You should try case when in where,

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE 
1 = case when ref_type = 'A' then 1 
    else
        case when ref = '1234' then 1 
        else
            case when (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND e_time = '10:30' AND place = 'work') or (e_date = '2015-08-03' AND place = 'work' AND person = 'tony') then 1 else 0 end 
        end
    end
```

It will check the conditions in ascending manner if any one the satisfy the criteria then it will not checking more.

Not sure about your exact conditions so that just putted here for the reference you should use that way to fulfill your need.